Specifying one of many keys for a DRF serializer response
I'm building an API to a spec which has been defined by a third party, the response returns a list of items, each specified by a key which indicates it's type.
example:
[
  {
    'someType': {
      'name': 'some type instance',
      'someTypeSpecificField': 'foo',
    }
  },
  {
    'someOtherType': {
      'name': 'some other type instance',
      'someOtherTypeSpecificField': 123,
    }
  },
  {
    'someType': {
      ...
    }
  },
  ...
]

Where each of the items in the response are derived from one model ie.
class SomeModel(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  type = models.ChoiceField()
  ...

I was curious what the best way to define this type of output might be using DRF serializers. Ideally it would be DRF-y enough to parse out properly in our AutoSchema, but any solutions are welcome.

My first thought would be to just have a normal serializer serialize that data and then to override the 'to_representation' method of the serializer to structure that data in a way you want. So you would esentially have normal data which would return the name and the type, and then restructure it so the key of the object is the type field. I don't know what more you are planning to do with it though, so can't offer advice there. This is the most DRF-y solution I can think of.

Again, I'm building according to a pre-defined spec so I can't reorganize the 'typeName': { ... } pattern
